# Easy way to copy cell value into another cell with same ID?

Tags: spss

There has to be an easier way than copying and pasting. I have a large dataset that has data on multiple rows for the same ID. I need to copy the date in one cell and move it to another cell in the same column, with each column having a different number of the same ID.

This page isn't allowing me to paste a photo and when I try to recreate it manually, it jumbles everything together on one line. Sigh.

I  have multiple IDs (ID1 ID1 ID1 ID2 ID2 ID3 ID3 ID3 ID3 ID3 ID3 ID4 ID4) on the column. In another column, I have a date, but only for the first ID of each sequence of IDs. Each subsequent cell in that column with the same ID is blank. I need to have that date in the last cell of each ID rather than the first.

Thanks!

Comment: look into `lag` and `lead` functions. As for putting a number table in your post - try the code formatting, that usually works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names of the ID and date variables are ID and date, and the cases are all sorted by ID so that all cases with the same ID are together, open a syntax window and try running the following:

```
IF ID=LAG(ID) date=LAG(date).
EXECUTE.
```

This should fill in the missing date values for subsequent dates for each ID.

If you must delete the dates for all cases except the last for each ID, you could do this as follows, after executing the above commands:

```
COMPUTE order=$CASENUM.
SORT CASES BY order(D).
IF ID=lag(ID) date=$SYSMIS.
SORT CASES BY order(A).
```